# Telegram phone number change

Tags: phone, accounts, instant-messaging

The instructions to change a phone number in Telegram messenger are not applicable to the Ubuntu phone.

I am not able to change my number in the settings menu.

Any ideas of how to change it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the number in your ubuntu Telegram aaccount. Just add the new number in the settings screen and then log out of your old number. You will still get all of your contacts via your new number.